# Bootstrap 4 - Flexbox examples not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, express, web

I am creating a simple Express webserver that serves a landing page made with bootstrap, but I can't get any Flexbox examples to work..

Below is my landing page, is there anything I am not seeing? I have checked that jQuery and Bootstrap links are working. I have also viewed the page in Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Homepage</title>

    <!-- STYLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/styleshee/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/stylesheets/main.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
        <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
        <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
        <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
    </div>

    <button id="test-btn" class="btn btn-success">Button</button>

    <!-- SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="../public/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/javascripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

As you can see **justify-content-around** is not behaving as expected. I have tried several Flexbox classes with the same results.

Comment: I should also mention that input-group-append and input-group-prepend is not working either.

Comment: navbar fixed-bottom is also behavig strange.. what am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: The markup should work fine. Make sure `bootstrap.css` is properly working and there are no console errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check which version of bootstrap you use.

When I try your code with version 3.xx it gives output like this in your question, but when I include bootstrap 4 css it gives this ( picture bellow)

[link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2AbK.png)

If you want something like this, just include this script for bootstrap css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @baduker Here is the explain for the first link, it is for prtscr of image.

Comment: @Pådne Welcome.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing one has to check is always sintax and grammar spelling!

Here is probably your mistake:

YOU WROTE "styleshee" instead of stylesheeT (or stylesheeTS)

check this out and let me know

Comment: I must have messed up the code when pasting it in the post, syntax looks fine